# R- normalizar columna

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de normalizar una columna y lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
totalData <- totalData %>% mutate_each_(funs(scale(.) %>% as.vector), 
                             vars=c("review_time"))
```

'review_time' es la única columna que quiero normalizar y es son valores enteros

Por qué da fallo?

El error mostrado es: *Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"*

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo el sentido de por que lo estás haciendo así `mutate_each_` y `funs()` se consideran deprecadas. Por lo que comentas alcanzaría con hacer `totalData %>% mutate(review_time = scale(review_time))`